# error: 'struct _DDSURFACEDESC2' has no member named 'DUMMYUNIONNAMEN'

Tags: c, winapi, directx

I'm trying to build an old application using a Windows XP Professional SP3 virtual machine. I set the environment with mingw and all is ok except for this error during building process:

```
error: 'struct _DDSURFACEDESC2' has no member named 'DUMMYUNIONNAMEN'
```

Seems that the ddraw.h header coming from mingw has a different structure. I tried to remove the DUMMYUNIONNAMEN from the source code like this:

```
// desc is passed as argument, initialized elsewhere
// desc type --> LPDDSURFACEDESC2
int depth = desc->DUMMYUNIONNAMEN(4).ddpfPixelFormat.DUMMYUNIONNAMEN(1).dwRGBBitCount;
```

that I replaced with this:

```
int depth = desc->ddpfPixelFormat.dwRGBBitCount;
```

In this way it builds but when I run the application I got sometimes an ACCESS VIOLATION error and sometimes (with different input file) no video (black window, only audio)

Comment: [The `DDSURFACEDESC2` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/drivers/ff550340(v=vs.85)) doesn't have a `DUMMYUNIONNAMEN` member. What book, tutorial or documentation are you reading that uses `DUMMYUNIONNAMEN`?

Comment: As for the "access violation" that's a crash, and you use a *debugger* to catch them and locate when and where they happen, and also examine variables and their values to see if that could give you a hint.

Comment: MinGW "Windows" headers are not official, there's a lot of headers missing, other not up to date, etc. The Windows SDK is the only official source for the Windows API. as for "sometimes" access violation, this is another story. Difficult to say w/o more code and/or reproducing project.

Comment: Those `DUMMYUNIONNAMEN` names aren't meant to be used. They had to be introduced since C (until C11) did not support anonymous unions. Client code should access the union fields instead, and ignore the union names. Your access violation is the result of defining a pointer (`LPDDSURFACEDESC2 desc;`) without initializing it, and then going ahead and using it as if it pointed to valid memory.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ddraw/ns-ddraw-ddpixelformat

Comment: @IInspectable sorry, my fault when reporting that piece of code. desc is passed to a method, I reported it only for showing the type

Comment: @SimonMourier in which way can I use the offical API with mingw? Is it ok to replace the headers?

Comment: Not sure sure there's a way (I'm not sure why mingw uses its own header, maybe a licensing issue). I use Visual Studio to program on Windows.

Comment: @SimonMourier I'll try installing Windows SDK and DirectX SDK (the last ones for Windows XP)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this is the ddraw.h from dx9sdk from Microsoft: https://pastebin.com/0RYVRE4R

Comment: [What are anonymous structs, and more importantly, how do I tell windows.h to stop using them?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170907-00/?p=96956)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *ddraw.h* from **dx9sdk** resolved the problem of **DUMMYUNIONNAMEN**. For the segmentation fault I opened another question